# Symfony2 classess and repository name

Tags: php, symfony

That is simple for you, but I can't understand the  difference (if it exist) between two "name" of this same class:

First if I use php function (`get_class()`) for some entity I get something like structure to directory to class of this object (`App\Module\Class`).

Second: If i want to get some data form db I have to use a repository name as `AppModule:Class`

So is there any method to transform first naming to second?
I don't know how you naming this two methods, I am sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: Don't confuse Doctine's AppModule:Class with PHP's AppModule::Class.  In the land of Doctine the AppModule is an alias which end up pointing to AppModule\Entity.  Class is then appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ClassName::class` where `ClassName` is whatever a class is, [you'll obtain the class FQCN](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) (Fully Qualified Class Name; in your example, for instance, `App\Module\Class`)

I suggest to use `ClassName::class` every time you can instead of `VendoBundle:Class` convention

This will work only if you use PHP >= 5.5 btw, but I hope you do!

Comment: Thak you for answer.

Is exist any (built-in) method to convert this two names? Like "App\Module\Class" to "AppModule:Class" ?

Comment: @Micchaleq I don't think so. However you don't need the second one, you can use what I've suggested even for repository retrieve. Give it a try!